# Can I compile java code that relies on a .class file and I don't have the source .java file?

Tags: java

I am trying to add two .class files to a .jar that came from a Vendor SDK that I want to modify. When I compile my two new .java files that depend on the classes in the .jar, can I compile them using -cp blahblahblah.jar or do I need to compile them using the classes themselves?

As a follow-up, am I able to compile file_1.java that's in the same package as file_2.java, but I only have file_2.class?

I have put my two .class files that I compiled using the .jar into the .jar itself but that seems like a destructive loop where it is compiled using itself. I feel I need to compile them using the package, but I don't have the .java files, only the .class files.

Comment: You normally put them on your class path even if not in jar files.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Am I able to put those compiled classes in the -cp in my javac command? Or am I able to compile my new file.java with the ,jar itself and then put my new .class files inside of the .jar?

Comment: Sure; compiling against bytecode is done all the time. Stuff that's in the same package is usually compiled all at once, though, and it's normally not a great idea to modify external jars.

Comment: This looks like a use case for a *dependency manager* like Maven.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you all for the clarification!

Comment: Yes, you can do this.  Don't modify the jar from the vendor - you'd be setting yourself up for all sorts of future problems.  Keep your own classes in your own jar.

Comment: Yes.  I would strongly recommend you read up on the "classpath" concept in order to do this correctly.  Java is not very helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can do javac with -cp option. However, since javac and java is very picky on classpath and dependencies, it will be better if you use a build tool such as Ant, Maven or Gradle.

**EDIT** - Added the example

Here is how it works in plain javac

**ImportedClass**

```
public class ImportedClass {
    public static void doThis() {
        System.out.println("This is from the Imported Class");
    }
}
```

**MainClass**

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("started");
    ImportedClass.doThis();
    System.out.println("Hurray!!!");
  }
}
```

Compiled ImportedClass.java first using `javac ImportedClass.java`
This will then create `ImportedClass.class` file. Don't keep this in the same directory, because by default `javac` takes the current directory as the classpath.

If you try to compile the `MainClass.java` without the `ImportedClass.class` in the classpath, we get a failure.

If we try to compile it with `-cp <folder>`, it is compiled.

[image]

However, this is a very basic example. For anything bigger than this, you might have to use [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Ant is too old and gradle is a little complicated than maven, so my two cents to Apache Maven

Comment: Hmm. I'm not a Java dev by trade and am much more familiar with Python. I am learning the basics of Java for this project and am having compilation flashbacks to C. I've seen Maven mentioned a lot and can see how something like it would be helpful. All I'm looking to do is add a file to an existing com\impinj\octane folder in a vendor supplied SDK, if it's necessary then it could be helpful. Any guidance on how _necessary_ it would be?

Comment: I just added an example using standard javac. If you need any help on maven, please edit the question here, or post a new question. But then google has a lot of references. You can tweet me (@aksappy) if you need any help. Cheers!